# How to run sql script in geany?

Tags: sqlite, ubuntu-12.04, geany

I am able to run my `ex1.sql` script from the command line, but in geany the follow error pops up:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: ./ex1: not found
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geany cannot execute sql directly. You have to configure the Build Commands from inside the build menu to do this e.g. to `psql -f %f` to run sql script with psql client.

Answer (score 0):

For me to work I did this
modify the filetypes.sql
this way:

```
[build-menu]
EX_00_LB=_Exécuter
EX_00_CM=/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -u root  <  %f
EX_00_WD=
```

`/opt/lampp/bin/mysql` = is where mysql is install on my computer
`<  %f`                =  allow the sql to be executed
dont forget to specify whitch DB you want to work with in your code
so put a line like  `use Mydatabase;`
at the top.